Inserting elements to an XML schema
I need a way of taking an xml schema and turning it into a completed xml document regardless of format. In particular, a way of inserting elements is required. The xmlschema library does not work with the document I am working with.
The xmlschema library has the following code for reading a file and inserting one element containing two subelements.
file      = "test.xsd"
schema   = xmlschema.XMLSchema(file) 
jsondata = json.dumps({'class': {"student1": "John",  \
                                 "student2": "Rachel"}})
    
nameSpace=schema.target_namespace
xml      = xmlschema.from_json(jsondata,schema=schema,preserve_root=True,namespaces={'': nameSpace})
# write to XML
ElementTree(xml).write('myxml.xml')

Which works fine to produce an xml from the simple test.xsd below.
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="class">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="student1"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="student2"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

However, the document I am working with has <xs:element name="class"/> below the body and as complex type above the iteration, which I do not know what this designates. I get a validation error. Reason: The content of (the first subelement) is not complete. Tag (first subelement) expected. How to fix this?
Below is a sample that should work with the first code block.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://address0.com" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ser="http://address0.com" xmlns:ds="http://www.address1.com">
    <xs:import namespace="http://www.address2.com" schemaLocation="xmldsig-core-schema.xsd"/>
    <xs:complexType name="class">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="student1" type="ser:String32" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="student2" type="ser:String32" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="class" type="ser:class"/>
    <xs:simpleType name="String32">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:normalizedString">
            <xs:minLength value="1"/>
            <xs:maxLength value="32"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>


Please add a relevante sample of the real xsd. You can also generate a sample xml from xsd to see how it looks like

@LMC Added. I do not see a much difference in the generated output xml compared to the example, but in the schema code the element "class" is given below.

minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" means that element must be provided once and only once. Will fail if not there.

@LMC I provided all 5 elements.
